# SystemVerilog assign derived class handle to base class object

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

This seems like a simple thing I should be able to do but I guess I don't fully understand polymorphism. I get a base class object from a monitor's analysis port and want to create a derived class object from this base class object, and then set extra members of the derived class (for coverage). What's the simplest way to go about doing this?

```
class BasePkt extends uvm_object;
  //...
endclass
.
class CovPkt extends BasePkt;
  //more members...
endclass
.
task process_pkt();
  forever begin
    BasePkt base_pkt;
    CovPkt cov_pkt;
    pkt_ap.get(base_pkt);
    cov_pkt = base_pkt; // Compile error
  end
endtask
```

I could create a function that performs a deep copy of BasePkt into a CovPkt object, but that doesn't seem like the right thing to do. Since CovPkt contains all the members of BasePkt, why can't I just assign it to a BasePkt class and then let the members of CovPkt that aren't in BasePkt be their default value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I just assign it to a BasePkt class and then let the members
> of CovPkt that aren't in BasePkt be their default value?

Because you can't.

When you make an assignment from one class variable to another, you are copying a class handle, not the class object itself. A handle is a *reference* to a constructed object. In your example, I presume `base_pkt` contains a handle to a `BasePkt` class object. The object only contains the space to hold the `BasePkt` members. If you were allowed to directly make an assignment of a `BasePkt` object to a `CovPkt` class variable, references to `CovPkt` members would be outside that space.

You were correct in needing to construct a `CovPkt` class object first, and then copying the `base_pkt` members. However, since you are using the UVM, a better approach is to simply create a `CovPkt` at the source in the Monitor by using the factory. You can override `BasePkt` with `CovPkt` without changing any code in the Monitor. Then you will be able to perform a dynamic cast in your task.

```
if (!$cast(cov_pkt,base_pkt)) `uvm_fatal(...);
```

You might want to take a look at my course on [SystemVerilog OOP for UVM](https://verificationacademy.com/courses/systemverilog-oop-for-uvm-verification).